# Passing html attribute value to the next script in php

Tags: php, html

I have three php scripts. main.php questions.php and values.php

Here's the code

**main.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Be Prepare for the battle</h1>
        <?php
            $strTitle = "Begin";
            $strLink = "<a href = 'question.php?ques_id=1'>" . $strTitle ."</a>";     
            echo $strLink;
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**questions.php**

```
<?php
require_once('../connect.php');
$quesSQL = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `questions` WHERE  `ques_id`=". $_GET["ques_id"]);

if(!mysql_num_rows($quesSQL) >= 1)
{
    die('Complete.');
}

$next = $_GET["ques_id"];

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($quesSQL)) {
    $id = $row['ques_id'];
    $strTitle = $row['ques_title'];
    echo "<li>" . $strTitle . "</li><br/>";         
}   

$optSQL = mysql_query("SELECT `options`,`values` FROM questions_options WHERE " . $id . "= ques_id");
echo "<form action=\"values.php\" method=\"POST\">";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($optSQL) ) {
    $strOptions = $row['options'];  
    $strValues = $row['values'];                            
    echo "<input type =\"radio\" name =\"valueIn\" value=" . $strValues . " />" . $strOptions . "<br/>";
}   
echo "</form>";
$strTitle = "<input type =\"submit\" value=\"Next\">";
$next = $next + 1;
$strLink = "<a href = 'values.php?ques_id=" . $next . "'>" . $strTitle ."</a>";
echo $strLink;

mysql_close();                  
?>
```

**values.php**

```
<?php
require_once('../connect.php'); 
$input = $_POST['valueIn'];
$ansSQL = mysql_query("SELECT `answer` FROM questions WHERE 1-".$_GET["ques_id"]."= ques_id");          

$marks = 0;         
if($input == $ansSQL)
{
    $marks = $marks+1;
}
else
{
    $marks = $marks+0;
}               
echo $marks;                            
?>
```

Now problem is i have to pass one value from second script(questions.php) to third script(values.php). 
And it is from the <form> section in radio button's name value "*valueIn*". But I can't do that. Because I'm sending another value ques_id with $strLink variable at the end of the second script.
So how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why your using a link to handle what should probably be in the form. As stated by anusha you should be using a hidden input field for ques_id like so

**questions.php**

```
<?php
    require_once('../connect.php');
    $quesSQL = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `questions` WHERE  `ques_id`=". $_GET["ques_id"]);

    if(!mysql_num_rows($quesSQL) >= 1)
    {
    die('Complete.');
}

$next = $_GET["ques_id"];

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($quesSQL)) {
    $id = $row['ques_id'];
    $strTitle = $row['ques_title'];
    echo "<li>" . $strTitle . "</li><br/>";         
}   

$optSQL = mysql_query("SELECT `options`,`values` FROM questions_options WHERE " . $id . "= ques_id");
echo "<form action=\"values.php\" method=\"POST\">";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($optSQL) ) {
    $strOptions = $row['options'];  
    $strValues = $row['values'];                            
    echo "<input type =\"radio\" name =\"valueIn\" value=" . $strValues . " />" . $strOptions . "<br/>";
}

$next = $next + 1;
$strLink = '<input type="hidden" name="ques_id" value="'.$next.'">';
echo $strLink;

    $strTitle = "<input type =\"submit\" value=\"Next\">";
    echo $strTitle;   
echo "</form>";

mysql_close();                  
?>
```

Both variables when then be available via $_POST on the next step like below

```
$input = $_POST['valueIn'];
$ques_id = $_POST['ques_id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use hidden input like Mike's answer, or you can still use GET parameter like this:

questions.php

```
<?php

// .........
// .........
// .........
// .........
// add / change your code for this part
$next = (int) $next;
$optSQL = mysql_query("SELECT `options`,`values` FROM questions_options WHERE ques_id = " . $next);
echo '<form action="values.php?ques_id=' . ($next+1) . '" method="POST">';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($optSQL) ) {
    $strOptions = $row['options'];
    $strValues = $row['values'];
    echo '<input type="radio" name ="valueIn" value="' . $strValues . '" />' . $strOptions . '<br/>';
}
echo '<input type="submit" value="Next">';
echo "</form>";
mysql_close();

// end change
?>
```

values.php

```
<?php
// add / change your code for this part
$_GET["ques_id"] = (int) $_GET["ques_id"];
$ansSQL = mysql_query("SELECT `answer` FROM questions WHERE ques_id = " . ($_GET["ques_id"]-1));
// end change
// .........
// .........
// .........
// .........
```

Comment: Thanks Husni for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple parameters with 'a' tag.
Like

```
 "<a href = 'values.php?ques_id=".$next." & ques_id1=1'>" . $strTitle ."</a>"
```

Comment: what he meant is to pass valueIn parameter, not the quest_id1

Comment: Instead of ques_id1 he can pass valueIn parameter.

Comment: I need to pass both valueIn and ques_id. Here with $strLink variable i passed ques_id, but at the same time can't pass ValueIn. If I use $strLink within form tag than valueIn passes but this time ques_id won't pass.

Comment: May be you don't look carefully to my script. I am already passes ques_id with $next variable @ sjkon

Answer (score -1):

You can also use a hidden input field for variable `$question_id` and submit the form

Comment: what he meant is to pass valueIn parameter, not the question_id

Comment: I understood the question. what i meant was the one @mike had stated above